# Retrieving error status from Haskell MongoDB driver

Tags: mongodb, haskell, error-handling

I have a MongoDB with one collection `user` that contains a unique index on `email`:

```
import Data.Bson        (Value (Int32))
import Database.MongoDB (Index (..), createIndex, (=:))

createIndex $ Index "user" [ "email" =: Int32 1 ] "email" True False
```

I have written a function that inserts a new user if the email address it is not already in use, and should fail if the email address is already taken:

```
import           Data.Bson        (Value (ObjId))
import           Database.MongoDB (Action, ObjectId, (=:))
import qualified Database.MongoDB as M (insert)

data User = User
  { email     :: Text
  , firstName :: Text
  , lastName  :: Text
  } deriving Show

data MongoEntity a = MongoEntity ObjectId a

createIfNotExists :: User
                  -> Action Handler (Either Text (MongoEntity User))
createIfNotExists (user@User {..}) = do
  value <- M.insert "user" [ "email" =: email
                           , "firstName" =: firstName
                           , "lastName" =: lastName
                           ]
  case value of
    ObjId objectId -> return (Right $ MongoEntity objectId user)
    _ -> return $ Left "no document"
```

I would like to detect any errors throw by the `M.insert` (such as a duplicate key) and return an
error `Text` message.

Since the `M.insert` runs in the `Action` monad, I assume it sets an error status if it fails, but I can't figure out how to retrieve it. I assume that I need something like

```
error <- getErrorStatus -- or whatever it is called
```

immediately after the `value <- M.insert ...` line and then test the error in the `case ... of` expression.

By the way, I tried writing `createIfNotExists` using `findAndModify` but I couldn't capture a failure with that either.

Comment: BTW, Here is a list of MongoDB error codes: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jean-Baptiste Potonnier's answer and after reading two articles by Michael Snoyman (http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/06/exceptions-transformers and https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/general-haskell/exceptions/exceptions-and-monad-transformers), I rewrote my code as follows:

```
import           Control.Exception.Lifted (handleJust)
import           Data.Bson                (Value (ObjId))
import qualified Data.Bson                as B (Value)
import qualified Data.Text                as T (pack)
import           Database.MongoDB         (Action, Failure (..), (=:))
import qualified Database.MongoDB         as M (insert)

createIfNotExists :: User -> Action Handler (Either Failure (MongoEntity User))
createIfNotExists user =
  handleJust writeFailureHandler (return . Left) $ do
    value <- insertUser user
    return $
      case value of
        ObjId objectId -> Right $ MongoEntity (T.pack $ show objectId) user
        _ -> error "Unexpected missing document"

  where
    writeFailureHandler :: Failure -> Maybe Failure
    writeFailureHandler writeFailure@WriteFailure{} = Just writeFailure
    writeFailureHandler _ = Nothing

insertUser :: User -> Action Handler B.Value
insertUser User{..} =
  M.insert "users" [ "email" =: email
                   , "firstName" =: firstName
                   , "lastName" =: lastName
                   ]
```

using the [`lifted-base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base) package.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this module, but reading the documentation, the best I could think of is :

Change the type for `createIfNotExists`

```
createIfNotExists :: MonadIO m =>
                     User -> Action m (Either String (MongoEntity User))
```

Use `catchJust` from `Control.Exception.Base`. The author seems to discourage the usage of `Control.Monad.Error.Class`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  pipe <- connect (host "127.0.0.1")
  let user = User "jd@bar.baz" "John" "Doe"
  eitherEntity <- catchJust writeFailureErrorStr
                  (access pipe master "user" $ createIfNotExists user)
                  (return . Left)
  close pipe

writeFailureErrorStr  :: Failure -> Maybe String
writeFailureErrorStr (WriteFailure _err str) = Just str
writeFailureErrorStr _other = Nothing
```

You probably want to check the `_err` code value too, since there could be other reasons for `WriteFailure`.

My understanding of the documentation is that it is not possible to handle errors out of IO.

I'm so confused by this way of doing that I think I'm probably wrong. Please show me a more elegant way if there is one.

More generally, I think that checking existence by try and fail is not very nice. I'd rather do a find request and insert if no result.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more reading of the library source code and was leaning toward catching the exception. Using a find followed by insert opens up a possible race condition, since MongoDB does not support transactions.